# ieee_arithmetic intrinsic module in gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I need to use gfortran to compile a library that is dependent on `ieee_arithmetic`. However, it is found that gfortran can not identify this module.

For example with the code `a.f90`

```
program test
   use,intrinsic :: ieee_arithmetic
   real :: x
   read *, x
   if (ieee_is_nan(x)) then
      print *, "Nan"
   else
   print *, "Not NaN"
end if
end program test
```

I have the following message when compiling

```
$ gfortran a.f90
a.f90:2.19:

use,intrinsic :: ieee_arithmetic
               1
Fatal Error: Can't find an intrinsic module named 'ieee_arithmetic' at (1)
```

How can I let gfortran know where the `ieee_arithmetic` intrinsic module is?

ifort is found to be able to use the `ieee_arithmetic` module. But I wish to make gfortran work for this case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The IEEE modules are supported as of GFortran version 5. See https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html  If you are using an older version, you should see the error message you have shown in your post.