# Fortran set NaN to zero

Tags: fortran

is there any way to set NaN (not a number) to zero in Fortran90

```
program testnan
implicit none

real :: x,y
x = -1
y = sqrt(x)
if(y.lt.0)then
y = 0
end if

print*, x, y

end program testnan
```

I tried some testing, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: I think some solutions might depend on your compiler. What are you using?

Comment: I'm using gfortran

Comment: A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747019/ieee-arithmetic-intrinsic-module-in-gfortran) covered the use of "ieee_is_nan(var)" to test if a variable is NaN. You'll have to use ieee_arithmetic, which requires gfortran 5 or greater. You might also be able to use the [isnan(var)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISNAN.html) function. Please let us know which worked best: I'd certainly like to know.

Comment: There were no standard way of doing this back in Fortran 90. Official support were added in Fortran2003 with 3 intrinsic modules (IEEE_FEATURES, IEEE_EXCEPTIONS and IEEE_ARITHMETIC). Is there anything that constrain you to use that specific old version of the language? Chances are your compiler already implements those modules.